# Implementing NAT Hairpin/Loopback for tcp hole punching

Tags: linux, networking, nat

I try to test a python hole punching packet based on this article: https://bford.info/pub/net/p2pnat/

The hole punching process worked in several network setups, only the final use case (3.5 Peers Behind Multiple Levels of NAT) gives me difficulties.

Let's assume the following network:

```
                  | 
                  | 11.0.0.1
             ___[eth0]___
               **NAT0**
             ___[eth1]___
                  | 192.168.0.1
                  |
               (switch)
                /    \
               /      \
  192.168.0.2 /        \ 192.168.0.3
        __[eth0]__   __[eth0]__
         **NATA**     **NATB**
        __[eth1]__   __[eth1]__
192.168.10.1|            |192.168.11.1
            |            |
192.168.10.2|            |192.168.11.2
        __[eth0]__   __[eth0]__
        **NodeA**    **NodeB**
```

I want to implement a hairpin on **NAT0** as I think this causes the issue. However I do not understand how to configure the `PREROUTING` and `POSTROUTING` as I do not know the public port from the PAT(=NAT). Thus I am not able to know which packet belongs to machine **NATA** or **NATB** only by checking the destination ip`-d 11.0.0.1` if I would now which public port belongs to **NATA** and **NATB** I would able to send the package to the right local machine.

The interesting thing is that I was able to get it working with only a single NAT layer (while not having configured a Hairpin at all).

**Possibly Related Question**

[How does NAT reflection (NAT loopback) work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282086/how-does-nat-reflection-nat-loopback-work)

However in this case all the (local) traffic with the destination of the public ip gets routed to a single machine. In my case I want to route the package to different machine depending on their public port.